# unable to execute VBoxManage command in python executable (created with pyinstaller)

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, executable, python3

OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

make an install.py file executable:

```
pyinstaller -w install.py --onefile
```

install.py script:

```
import os
VM = os.system('VBoxManage startvm win10 --type headless')
if VM == 0:
   print("win10 started...")
else:
   print("win10 not started....")
```

**Problem:** When I run the `python3 install.py` on ubuntu terminal it works fine. After that I created it's an executable file with the command mentioned above and when I execute the executable file on the terminal by giving command `chmod 777 install & ./install`. It gives an error below:

**Error:**

```
VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the VirtualBox object!
VBoxManage: error: Code NS_ERROR_FACTORY_NOT_REGISTERED (0x80040154) - Class not registered (extended info not available)
VBoxManage: error: Most likely, the VirtualBox COM server is not running or failed to start.
```

I don't know what's going wrong python script works fine but when I created it's executable it gives same error every time.

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: What exactly does the `install` program do? Wouldn't it be simpler to just add `#!/usr/bin/python3` to the top of your install.py script?

Comment: It's just stared virtual machine in VirtualBox with name win10. It works fine with ```python3 install.py``` but when I create executable file using pyinstaller it only gives VBoxManage error.  Can you please explain why I need to add this in my install.py script ```#!/usr/bin/python3```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/python3` on the very first line is a so called "shebang" that tells the kernel which interpreter to use for a script.  Add the line, `chmod +x script.py` (never 777) and run `./script.py`.

Comment: @OskarSkog thanks for your response. I actually want to secure my code, that's why I am making executable file. and there is no need to add ```#!/usr/bin/python3``` . Because all the required libraries are also packed in that executable file.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: That sounds really unnecessary.  Python + standard modules are pre-installed on practically every linux distribution.  //  Does running the VBoxManage command work anymore? (Ie. Is this a problem with Virtualbox, or with Pyinstaller?)

Comment: @OskarSkog seriously I don't know where the issue is, because install.py script worked very well but generate the issue with executable as mentioned above.  Maybe running VBoxManage command from an executable file causes an issue or maybe some other issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108039/discussion-between-oskar-skog-and-ahsan-azeem).